# Simple Barchart values swapped

Tags: d3.js

I'm attempting to create a bar simple chart using some data I got from the internet. The data includes 300 individuals of which 260 do not have a cable TV subscription, 40 of which do. this leads to 13% having a subscription and 87% not. Ive set up the yscale to take in these values and everything seems fine although for some reason my subscribed bar is 87% and my not subscribed bar is 13% I'm trying to find the flaw in my code but I have yet to encounter it. Does anyone know why my values are swapped when rendering?

```
const rowConverter = (row) => {
    row = {
        age: parseInt(row.age),
        gender: row.gender,
        income: parseInt(row.income),
        kids: parseInt(row.kids),
        ownHome: row.ownHome === "true",
        subscribed: row.subscribed === "true",
        segment: row.segment
    }
    return { ...row };
};

const dataset = await d3.csv("./data/CableTVSubscribersData.csv", rowConverter);
const margin = {
    top: 40,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 60,
    right: 20
};
const width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let subscribedCounter = 0;
let notSubscribedCounter = 0;

dataset.forEach(data => {
    if (data.subscribed) {
        subscribedCounter++
    }
    else {
        notSubscribedCounter++;
    }
});
let barChartRows = [
    {
        name: "Subscribed",
        amount: subscribedCounter
    },
    {
        name: "Not Subscribed",
        amount: notSubscribedCounter
    },
];

const dataset2 = barChartRows;
const barNames = dataset2.map((d) => d.name)

const svg = d3.select(".graph1")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")


svg.append('rect')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style("fill", "#e6e6e6");

let xScale2 = d3.scaleBand()
.domain(barNames)
.rangeRound([0, width- margin.left ]);

let yScale2 = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .rangeRound([height - margin.top, 0]);

let xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(xScale2);
let yAxis2 = d3.axisLeft(yScale2);


let xAxisGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'groupAxis')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left + margin.right}, ${height})`)
    .call(xAxis2);

let yAxisGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'incomeAxis')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left + margin.right},${margin.top})`)
    .call(yAxis2)
    .selectAll("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d3.format(".0%")(d) });

    console.log(dataset2);
    svg.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(dataset2)
        .join(
            enter => enter
            .append('rect')
            .attr("class",(d) => d.name)
            .attr('x',(d) => xScale2(d.name)+(margin.left + margin.right)*2+10})
            .attr('y',(d) => height - yScale2(d.amount/300))
            .attr('width',150)
            .attr('height',(d) => yScale2(d.amount/300)})
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add a minimal reproducible example. That will make it easier for others to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the range in your Y scale so the yScale2 function will give you the right height for the bar.